# I want to access my apache server running of ubuntu 20.04 from any device(phone,pc,etc) connected to internet

Tags: networking, server, apache2, iptables, firewall

I am a beginner and have no idea how to make my machine public.
I am using WIFI USB card adapter for internet,and uses android phone as hotspot.

**This is the output of route -n**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlxd03745b828ea
```

**This is the output of ifconfig**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:8d:5c:a5:eb:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5249  bytes 490718 (490.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5249  bytes 490718 (490.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxd03745b828ea: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.152  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::2a06:7ce0:e44b:36d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:37:45:b8:28:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4865  bytes 57887713 (57.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 287  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5067  bytes 6296300 (6.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 35 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**This is the output of status ufw status**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for frozenmafia: 
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**This is the output of sudo netstat -tlpn**

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~$ sudo netstat -tlpn
[sudo] password for frozenmafia: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2365/smbd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      683/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      733/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2365/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      2365/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      973/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      733/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      2365/smbd
```

I am attesting my public IP data.

[This contains my public IP information with port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J641r.png)

[This contains my public IP information with port 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZIEA.png)

I am able access my webpage on my phone browser and UBUNTU desktop but not on any other device.

Now, I do not know how to proceed and what to do.Is my setup OK? Will this work?
I would highly obliged if anyone explains me in simple language and a permanent solution.

Thank you

Comment: Can I confirm the situation? Your computer is tethered to your phone, and you want people to access Apache via that connection?

Comment: Could you do a ´netstat -tlpn´ and add that information to your question?

Comment: You have to tell Android to forward the ports to your Ubuntu, not sure if this is possible. But anyways, there is nothing you need to do on Ubuntu side, so imo, this is off-topic here. This is better placed in an Android forum. BTW: I would **not** do that.

Comment: Check this maybe: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168422/how-to-port-forward-internet-using-android-hotspot-to-pc/207342

Comment: @Matigo I am using phone's hotspot.Yes I want to access apache via that connection.

Comment: @s1mmel I have added what you told me to add.

Comment: Be aware that this working via your phone also depends on your carrier allowing the incoming traffic

Comment: @M_dk thanks for your comment.I will to contact customer care.

Comment: @pLumo I have already done what you suggested, But I do not know how to verify what I did was correct or incorrect.

Comment: If we understand your situation correctly, my answer to [How to port-forward internet using Android Hotspot to PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/218526) as already suggested by pLumo answers your question.

Comment: The apache webserver is only serving the IPv6 address, but not IPv4.